# In Ruby, how would one create new CSV's conditionally from an original CSV?

Tags: excel, ruby

I'm going to use this as sample data to simplify the problem:
[data_set_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqTXM.png)

I want to split the contents of this csv according to Column A - DEPARTMENT and place them on new csv's named after the department.

If it were done in the same workbook (so it can fit in one image) it would look like:
[data_set_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkCHx.png)

My initial thought was something pretty simple like:

```
CSV.foreach('test_book.csv', headers: true) do |asset|
   CSV.open("/import_csv/#{asset[1]}", "a") do |row|
     row << asset
   end
 end
```

Since that should take care of the logic for me. However, from looking into it, CSV#foreach does not accept file access rights as second parameter, and it gets an error when I run it. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please show `data_set_1` and `data_set_2` as text so that readers can cut-and-paste. In general it's best to avoid linking to pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would need to pass file access rights to `CSV#foreach`. This method just *reads* the CSV. How I would do this is like so:

```
# Parse the entire CSV into an array.
orig_rows = CSV.parse(File.read('test_book.csv'), headers: true)

# Group the rows by department.
# This becomes { 'deptA' => [<rows>], 'deptB' => [<rows>], etc }
groups = orig_rows.group_by { |row| row[1] }

# Write each group of rows to its own file
groups.each do |dept, rows|
  CSV.open("/import_csv/#{dept}.csv", "w") do |csv|
    rows.each do |row|
      csv << row.values
    end
  end
end
```

A caveat, though. This approach *does* load the entire CSV into memory, so if your file is very large, it wouldn't work. In that case, the "streaming" approach (line-by-line) that you show in your question would be preferrable.

Comment: It doesn't appear that the CSV file contains headers. If it did one could add `headers = CSV.open('test_book.csv') { |csv| csv.first }` before `CSV.open("/import_csv/#{dept}.csv", "w") do |csv|` and `csv << headers` after the same.

Comment: I like your solution a lot, but it's running into the same error I'm getting with my initial solution.
`/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv.rb:640:in 'initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /import_csv/HR.csv (Errno::ENOENT)`

Comment: You must not have the folder `/import_csv` existing. Maybe you need to change that to a relative path?